# Unable to Store Base64 Data in MySql Database

Tags: php, mysql, string, base64

I am trying to store an Base64 string to my MySql database using PHP. Here is my code.

```
<?PHP
//Store Image
$photoData = $_POST['PhotoData'];

//Database connection details
$db_url = "192.168.1.140";
$db_user_name = "easyblogadmin";
$db_password = "admin";
$db_name = "easyblog";

$con = mysqli_connect($db_url, $db_user_name, $db_password);
$sql = "insert into temptable (photodata) values('$photoData')";

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to Connect Database";
        echo mysqli_connect_errno();
        die();
    } else {
        //Connecting to Application Database
        $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($con, $db_name);
        if(!$db_selected){
            echo "Failed to Connect Application Database";
            die();
        } else {
            if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
                die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            }
            mysqli_close($con);
            echo "Successfully Added photo".strlen($photoData);
        }
    }?>
```

Here the $photoData is my Base64 encoded string and I am storing this in my DB. When i am trying to retrieve this data from DB some data in my string is missing. I don't understand why this is happening. Can any one help me out.

regards.

Comment: What is the contents of `$sql` before you execute it?

Comment: Try with Increase the length of that field in database

Comment: What is the structure of your table?

Comment: @lc - The content is an Image encoded to Base64

Comment: The type of the photodata column in my database table is longtext. This table consists only two fields S.No and ptotodata.

Comment: Is this question helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335278/prepared-mysqli-select-statement-on-longtext-field-is-coming-back-empty

Comment: did you kept the datatype for photodata column in database as text

Comment: @Venkat i am uing longtext as datatype for photodata

Comment: try text datatype instead of longtext

Comment: I tried it but getting the same issue. Present photodata length is 293422.

Comment: Is post_max_size set high enough in php.ini?

Answer (score 0):

chnage the sql query as below mentioned

```
$sql = "insert into databasename.temptable (photodata) values('$photoData')";
```

also please make sure if the encoded value has any single quotes,if it is then replace the data as mentioned below .

```
$photoData =str_replace("'","\'",$_POST['PhotoData']);
```